# CSS transition on hidden div

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, hidden

I have a div that displays and hides on a jquery click function and I want to add css transition on the div. This is done by adding and a remove a class .hidden and .visible, here is the jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#search-icon").on( "click", function() {

                if ($("#display-search").hasClass("hidden")) {
                    $("#display-search").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                }
                 else {
                    $("#display-search").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                }

                });

            });
    </script>
```

and the css for .hidden .visible:

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition:  height 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay:0.2s;}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition:  height 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay:0.2s;}
```

Does anyone have any ideas for how I can get the transition to work and what I am doing wrong? Do I need to add a height/max-height to the classes? I also tried adding the transition to the div #display-search but that also had no effect.

Comment: you are transitioning the `height ` property. change it to "all" or "opacity": transition: all 0.5s ease;

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-transition:  height 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: height 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: height 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: height 0.5s ease;
transition: height 0.5s ease;
```

Because you specify height in the transition, only the height will animate. Change it to:

```
-webkit-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
```

or:

```
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: 0.5s ease;
transition: 0.5s ease;
```

To animate the opacity.

**UPDATE**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uq76jtov/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#search-icon").on("click", function () {

        if ($("#display-search").hasClass("visible")) {
            $("#display-search").removeClass("visible");
        } else {
            $("#display-search").addClass("visible");
        }

    });

});
```

```css
#display-search {
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;
}
#display-search.visible {
    visibility:visible;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="search-icon">Search</span>

<div id="display-search"></div>
```

Comment: Ideally I am trying achieve a transition like they have here https://www.harrys.com/ when you click on 'About Harry's' in the menu, and I saw that they were using the height selector for their transition. I tried changing it to the ones you suggested but still no luck.

Comment: @BenThompson I see your point. I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work :)

you did use the height for transition, not the opacity

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

                $("#search-icon").on( "click", function() {

                if ($("#display-search").hasClass("hidden")) {
                    $("#display-search").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                }
                 else {
                    $("#display-search").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
                }

                });

            });
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition:   opacity 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay:0.2s;}

.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition:   opacity 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition:  opacity 0.5s ease;
  transition-delay:0.2s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="search-icon">click me!</button>
<div id="display-search" class="visible">heyho</div>
```