# Can someone help me translate this jQuery code to JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

im having huge trouble trying to translate this code to js

i spent my whole day on this and i have no idea how to translate the .not and .filter function into js. I read multiple guides into translating jquery code into js but im slowly starting to give up on this

i added the js code with html and css to the other code snippet

```js
    // jQuery
    $('.list').click(function(){
        const value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        if (value == 'All'){
            $('.imagebox').show('1000');
        }
        else {
            $('.imagebox').not('.'+value).hide('1000');
            $('.imagebox').filter('.'+value).show('1000');
        }
    })
    // add active class on selected item
    $('.list').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
let ready = (callback) => {
  if (document.readyState != "loading") callback()
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback)
}

ready(() => {
  var baseUrl = "/1/obrazki/";

  // loading and listing files
  function getFiles() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", baseUrl, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var elements = xhr.response.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (x of elements) {
          let imagebox;
          if (x.href.match(/\.(webp)$/)) {
            imagebox = document.createElement("div");
            imagebox.className = "imagebox";
            let img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = x.href;
            imagebox.appendChild(img);
            document.getElementById("viewer").appendChild(imagebox);
          }

          // add classes from array
          let datatypes = ["logo", "thumbnail", "graphic"]
          for (var i of datatypes)
            if (x.href.indexOf(i) > -1) {
              imagebox.classList.toggle(i, true)
              console.log(imagebox.classList);
            }
          // navbar sorting
          let el = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
          // loop to check if array of 'list' elements are clicked
          for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            el[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
              const value = this.getAttribute("data-filter")
              console.log(imagebox.className)
              if (value == "imagebox") {
                imagebox.style.display = "block";
              } else {
                if (imagebox.classlist.contains(value)) {
                  imagebox.style.display = "none"
                }
              }
            });
          }
        };
      } else {
        alert('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
      }
    }
    xhr.send()
  }
  getFiles();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #242424;
}

#viewer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.imagebox {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.imagebox img {
  position: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.GalleryContainer {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  padding: 20px;
}

.GalleryContainer ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.GalleryContainer ul li {
  list-style: none;
  background: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  color: #eee;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.GalleryContainer ul li.active {
  background: #f4d003;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js%22%3E"></script> -->
  <script src="gallery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="GalleryContainer">
    <ul>
      <li class="list active" data-filter="imagebox">All</li>
      <li class="list" data-filter="thumbnail">Thumbnails</li>
      <li class="list" data-filter="logo">Logos</li>
      <li class="list" data-filter="graphic">Graphics</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="viewer"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it looks like you want `imagebox.classList.contains(value)`. You also don't need to prepend the dot in front of a class unless you're using it as a selector.

Comment: imagebox elements are created by a script

Comment: You can copy the generated HTML from DOM, then edit it in a text editor to make it small...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost there, the parts where the logic needs amendment is around the retrieval of siblings and the addition/removal of the classes.

In addition the two jQuery event handlers can be brought together as they both target the same event on the same collection of `.list` elements. Try this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.list').forEach(list => {
  list.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const value = e.target.dataset.filter;
    document.querySelectorAll('.imagebox').forEach(imagebox => {
      imagebox.style.display = (value == 'All' || imagebox.classList.contains(value)) ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
    
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    Array.from(e.target.parentNode.children).forEach(sibling => {
      if (sibling != e.target)
        sibling.classList.remove('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<div class="list active" data-filter="All">All</div>
<div class="list" data-filter="foo">Foo</div>
<div class="list" data-filter="bar">Bar</div>

<div class="imagebox foo">imagebox - foo</div>
<div class="imagebox bar">imagebox - bar</div>
<div class="imagebox foo">imagebox - foo</div>
<div class="imagebox bar">imagebox - bar</div>
```

The slight difference in the plain JS version is that it does not animate the transitions in the way that jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` methods do. You would need to implement that yourself. It can be done using CSS though, adding/removing classes to toggle the element's visibility using the `transition` rule.

Comment: IT WORKED PERFECTLY

Comment: Glad it helped :) I just made a small tweak to the logic to make it a bit more succinct.

Comment: its a bit hard to understand everything in your js code but it works as intended, i started doing functions through jquery and ajax because it was easier, but i ended up deciding to rewrite my script to plain JS to not have any issues mixing js and jquerry
(jquerry also sadly has some issues loading on some webservers)

Comment: If you need to look anything up in my code, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) has a fantastic reference which lists all the methods.  Just a couple of notes on your last comment though: '*i ended up deciding to rewrite my script to plain JS to not have any issues mixing js and jquerry*' - mixing JS and jQuery will work fine. Most people's problem with it is only due to consistency of codebase language. '*jquerry also sadly has some issues loading on some webservers*' jQuery is a client side framework, so shouldn't be affected by the type of webserver.

Comment: how do i set the transition rule to the .imagebox class in css? do i use pseudo classes?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32626273/519413

Comment: i added 2 ifs that check if imagebox.style.display is block or none and then it adds/removes a visible or hidden class which i gave an opacity and transition rule in css
but it doesent seem to animate it
 ```js
if (imagebox.style.display == 'block') {
       imagebox.classList.remove('hidden');
       imagebox.classList.add('visible');
      }
      if (imagebox.style.display == 'none') {
       imagebox.classList.remove('visible');
       imagebox.classList.add('hidden');
      }```

Comment: this 'funtion' works but the konsole prints out that imagebox is undefined

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question about it, including all the code you've added to perform the transition

Answer (score 0):

I think you code will look something like this:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
const imageBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("imagebox");
const imageBoxesArr = Array.from(imageBoxes);
Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const value = this.getAttribute("data-filter");
    if (value === "All") {
      toggleImageBoxesVisibility(imageBoxesArr, false);
    } else {
      toggleImageBoxesVisibility(imageBoxesArr, el.classList.contains(value));
    }
  });
});

function toggleImageBoxesVisibility(imagesBoxesArr, hide) {
  imageBoxesArr.forEach(el => {
    el.classLis.toggle('hidden', hide);
  });
}
```

Of course there might be some small issues since I can't test it myself